# Have a ScrollView inside a KeyboardAvoidingView that takes at least 100% height to layout children with flexbox

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to implement a login form that layouts its children with flexbox. It contains two components, the app logo and the login form. The logo should take 33% of the viewports height, the form should take 66%.

This is relatively easy with flexbox. Just set `flex: 1` on the logo and `flex: 2` on the form.

Wrapping the whole screen in `KeyboardAvoidingView` works fine – the flex layout shrinks as soon as the keyboard appears, but the user now can't see the bottom elements of the form, since they can't fit in the area above the keyboard.

The obvious solution would be to wrap the form in a `ScrollView` and wrap that in a KeyboardAvoidingView, but then the whole form flexbox layout stops working. The content container of the ScrollView will only be as tall as the children, it won't take the full viewport height.

I made an expo Snack showing my layout: https://snack.expo.io/rydF0b4O-

I need the layout to be scrollable when it can't show all children, but it seems to be impossible to do that with a ScrollView. (Click the second button to toggle the ScrollView in the layout)